# "Cannot resolve scoped service from root provider" with custom EF Core SeriLog Sink

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi, serilog

I'm trying to create a custom SeriLog sink that ties to EntityFrameworkCore.  I found an existing one called [Serilog.Sinks.EntityFrameworkCore](https://github.com/vincentgury/Serilog.Sinks.EntityFrameworkCore) but it used its own DbContext and I need to be able to use an existing DbContext.

So, I basically created my own version of the code that works with my DbContext.  However, every time the Emit method gets called and it tries to load the DbContext, I get the following error:

`Cannot resolve scoped service ... from root provider`

I have seen other posts regarding this issue that involve scoped services and middleware.  However, I don't believe that what I've got is middleware.

In a nutshell, here are the core pieces of my code (again, most of which is copied from the previously mentioned Git Repo).

**startup.cs**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
   services.AddDbContext<EligibilityDbContext>(opts => opts.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("EligibilityDbConnection")));
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app,
                      IHostingEnvironment env, 
                      SystemModelBuilder modelBuilder, 
                      ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
   Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
       .WriteTo.EntityFrameworkSink(app.ApplicationServices.GetService<EligibilityDbContext>)
.CreateLogger();

loggerFactory.AddSeriLog();
}
```

**EntityFrameworkSinkExtensions.cs**

```
public static class EntityFrameworkSinkExtensions
{
    public static LoggerConfiguration EntityFrameworkSink(
        this LoggerSinkConfiguration loggerConfiguration,
        Func<EligibilityDbContext> dbContextProvider,
        IFormatProvider formatProvider = null) 
    {
        return loggerConfiguration.Sink(new EntityFrameworkSink(dbContextProvider, formatProvider));
    }
}
```

**EntityFrameworkSink.cs**

```
public class EntityFrameworkSink : ILogEventSink
{
    private readonly IFormatProvider _formatProvider;
    private readonly Func<EligibilityDbContext> _dbContextProvider;
    private readonly JsonFormatter _jsonFormatter;
    static readonly object _lock = new object();

    public EntityFrameworkSink(Func<EligibilityDbContext> dbContextProvider, IFormatProvider formatProvider)
    {
        _formatProvider = formatProvider;
        _dbContextProvider = dbContextProvider ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(dbContextProvider));
        _jsonFormatter = new JsonFormatter(formatProvider: formatProvider);
    }

    public void Emit(LogEvent logEvent)
    {
        lock (_lock)
        {
            if (logEvent == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            try
            {
                var record = ConvertLogEventToLogRecord(logEvent);

                //! This is the line causing the problems!
                DbContext context = _dbContextProvider.Invoke();

                if (context != null)
                {
                    context.Set<LogRecord>().Add(this.ConvertLogEventToLogRecord(logEvent));

                    context.SaveChanges();
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                // ignored
            }
        }
    }

    private LogRecord ConvertLogEventToLogRecord(LogEvent logEvent)
    {
        if (logEvent == null)
            return null;

        string json = this.ConvertLogEventToJson(logEvent);

        JObject jObject = JObject.Parse(json);
        JToken properties = jObject["Properties"];

        return new LogRecord
        {
            Exception = logEvent.Exception?.ToString(),
            Level = logEvent.Level.ToString(),
            LogEvent = json,
            Message = logEvent.RenderMessage(this._formatProvider),
            MessageTemplate = logEvent.MessageTemplate?.ToString(),
            TimeStamp = logEvent.Timestamp.DateTime.ToUniversalTime(),
            EventId = (int?)properties["EventId"]?["Id"],
            SourceContext = (string)properties["SourceContext"],
            ActionId = (string)properties["ActionId"],
            ActionName = (string)properties["ActionName"],
            RequestId = (string)properties["RequestId"],
            RequestPath = (string)properties["RequestPath"]
        };
    }

    private string ConvertLogEventToJson(LogEvent logEvent)
    {
        if (logEvent == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        using (StringWriter writer = new StringWriter(sb))
        {
            this._jsonFormatter.Format(logEvent, writer);
        }

        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

The error occurs in EntityFrameworkSink.cs on the line `DbContext context = _dbContextProvider.Invoke();`

Any thoughts on why this is throwing an error and how to get this working?

**Update**

Based on Eric's comments, I updated my startup.cs code as follows:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, SystemModelBuilder modelBuilder, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, IServiceProvider provider)
{
   Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
      .WriteTo.EntityFrameworkSink(provider.GetService<EligibilityDbContext>)
      .CreateLogger();
}
```

Now I get the error: `Cannot access a disposed object. Object name: IServiceProvider`

**Caveat To Answer**

So I marked Tao Zhou's answer as the answer.  However, it was not what he said but the code he provided that actually provided the answer.  I don't believe that `EmitBatchAsync` will actually resolve what my issue was -- however, I've run across a couple other comments, etc. elsewhere that indicate that it may help improve performance.

What actually resolved the problem was following his code sample.  In startup, he is passing `app.ApplicationServices`.  Then, in the actual Sink implementation, he created a scope for resolving an instance of the dbContext:

```
using(var context = service.CreateScope().ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<EligibilityDbContext>())
{
}
```

This actually resolved all the errors I was getting and got this working the way I had expected.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For using `Serilog` with `EF Core`, you may need to implement `PeriodicBatchingSink` instead of `ILogEventSink`.

Follow steps below:

1. Install package `Serilog.Sinks.PeriodicBatching`
2. `EntityFrameworkCoreSinkExtensions`

   ```
   public static class EntityFrameworkCoreSinkExtensions
   {
   public static LoggerConfiguration EntityFrameworkCoreSink(
             this LoggerSinkConfiguration loggerConfiguration,
             IServiceProvider serviceProvider,
             IFormatProvider formatProvider = null)
   {
       return loggerConfiguration.Sink(new EntityFrameworkCoreSink(serviceProvider, formatProvider, 10 , TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)));
   }
   }
   ```
3. `EntityFrameworkCoreSink`

   ```
      public class EntityFrameworkCoreSink : PeriodicBatchingSink
      {
   private readonly IFormatProvider _formatProvider;
   private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;
   private readonly JsonFormatter _jsonFormatter;
   static readonly object _lock = new object();

   public EntityFrameworkCoreSink(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, IFormatProvider formatProvider, int batchSizeLimit, TimeSpan period):base(batchSizeLimit, period)
   {
       this._formatProvider = formatProvider;
       this._serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
       this._jsonFormatter = new JsonFormatter(formatProvider: formatProvider);
   }

   protected override async Task EmitBatchAsync(IEnumerable<LogEvent> events)
   {
       using (var context = _serviceProvider.CreateScope().ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>())
       {
           if (context != null)
           {
               foreach (var logEvent in events)
               {
                   var log = this.ConvertLogEventToLogRecord(logEvent);
                   await context.AddAsync(log);
               }
               await context.SaveChangesAsync();
           }
       }
   }

   private LogRecord ConvertLogEventToLogRecord(LogEvent logEvent)
   {
       if (logEvent == null)
       {
           return null;
       }

       string json = this.ConvertLogEventToJson(logEvent);

       JObject jObject = JObject.Parse(json);
       JToken properties = jObject["Properties"];

       return new LogRecord
       {
           Exception = logEvent.Exception?.ToString(),
           Level = logEvent.Level.ToString(),
           LogEvent = json,
           Message = this._formatProvider == null ? null : logEvent.RenderMessage(this._formatProvider),
           MessageTemplate = logEvent.MessageTemplate?.ToString(),
           TimeStamp = logEvent.Timestamp.DateTime.ToUniversalTime(),
           EventId = (int?)properties["EventId"]?["Id"],
           SourceContext = (string)properties["SourceContext"],
           ActionId = (string)properties["ActionId"],
           ActionName = (string)properties["ActionName"],
           RequestId = (string)properties["RequestId"],
           RequestPath = (string)properties["RequestPath"]
       };
   }

   private string ConvertLogEventToJson(LogEvent logEvent)
   {
       if (logEvent == null)
       {
           return null;
       }

       StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
       using (StringWriter writer = new StringWriter(sb))
       {
           this._jsonFormatter.Format(logEvent, writer);
       }

       return sb.ToString();
   }
   }
   ```
4. `Startup`

   ```
       public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
   {
       Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                           .WriteTo.EntityFrameworkCoreSink(app.ApplicationServices)
                           .CreateLogger();
       loggerFactory.AddSerilog();
   ```

   Source Code:[StartupEFCore](https://github.com/Edward-Zhou/AspNetCore/blob/master/SerilogPro/StartupEFCore.cs)

Comment: Can you explain why using PeriodicBatchingSync would work better than ILogEventSink in this case?  I'm having difficulty understanding why this would make a difference.

Comment: @RHarris For implementating `ILogEventSink` directly, it will be sync operation and will open new connection while writing logs which might block the application and sql connection. For `PeriodicBatchingSink`, `EmitBatchAsync` will be async and will submit the logs in batch.

Answer (score 3):

When you call `app.ApplicationServices.GetService<EligibilityDbContext>`, you're directly resolving a [scoped service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-2.1#scope-validation) from the application container which isn't allowed. If you add EligibilityDbContext as a parameter to the Configure method, it will generate a scope and inject the context into your method.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, ..., EligibilityDbContext context)
{
  // ... use context
}
```

Comment: Actually, given how it's being used, you may want to take an IServiceProvider instead so you can pass the GetService call as a delegate.

Comment: I thought that's what I was doing -- passing GetService call as a delegate.  In my code, I'm passing `app.ApplicationServices.GetService<EligibilityDbContext>` as a parameter for `Func<EligibilityDbContext>` in my EntityFrameworkSink Extension method.

Comment: Yes, but you can't use `app.ApplicationServices` to resolve a scoped dependency. You should be able to inject an IServiceProvider into the Configure method and use it in the same way, though.

Comment: So I just tried that but now I get an error about not being able to used a disposed object.

Comment: Hmmm, I guess the services passed to the Configure() call just exist within a scope that lasts for the lifespan of the Configure call, so it's disposed by the time the logger would actually call it. You could try `app.ApplicationServices.CreateScope().ServiceProvider.GetService<T>()`. That will create a scope for the log provider that isn't disposed (unless you dispose it), but creating a scope that's basically a singleton feels dirty.

Comment: So maybe I'm learning why SeriLog doesn't already provide an "approved" sink for EntityFramework. :)

Comment: @EricDamtoft  `app.ApplicationServices.CreateScope().ServiceProvider.GetService<T>()` worked for me. Thanks!